# Using php arrays to validate form information

Tags: php

I am not sure if this question has been answered in round about ways through other questions but...

I am creating a web page for my job which has multiple entry fields (all of which have the same validation code). The following is a small section of my php code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["bottomair"])) {
    $bottomairerror = "Maketable bottom air temp is required";
    } else {
        $bottomair = test_input($_POST["bottomair"]);
        if (!filter_var($bottomair, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $bottomairerror = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["topair"])) {
        $topairerror = "Maketable top air temp is required";
    } else {
        $topair = test_input($_POST["topair"]);
        if (!filter_var($topair, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $topairerror = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["meat"])) {
        $meaterror = "Maketable meat temp is required";
    } else {
        $meat = test_input($_POST["meat"]);
        if (!filter_var($meat, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $meaterror = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["cheese"])) {
        $cheeseerror = "Maketable cheese temp is required";
    } else {
        $cheese = test_input($_POST["cheese"]);
        if (!filter_var($cheese, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $cheeseerror = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["walkin"])) {
        $walkinerror = "Walk-In temp is required";
    } else {
        $walkin = test_input($_POST["walkin"]);
        if (!filter_var($walkin, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $walkinerror = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["refrig1"])) {
        $refrig1error = "Refrigerator #1 temp is required";
    } else {
        $refrig1 = test_input($_POST["refrig1"]);
        if (!filter_var($refrig1, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $refrig1error = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["refrig2"])) {
        $refrig2error = "Refrigerator #2 temp is required";
    } else {
        $refrig2 = test_input($_POST["refrig2"]);
        if (!filter_var($refrig2, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $refrig2error = $errormsg;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["refrig3"])) {
        $refrig3error = "Refrigerator #3 temp is required";
    } else {
        $refrig3 = test_input($_POST["refrig3"]);
        if (!filter_var($refrig3, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) {
            $refrig3error = $errormsg;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a function which I can use to "tidy up" my php code so that I do not have as many lines to debug when things go sideways with the coding?

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have three options here:

1. Write perfect code so that your code never goes sideways (highly unlikely for any developer :)
2. Change from an if structure to a [switch structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)
3. Evolve your debugging procedure/tools to make debugging less painful in general.

Comment: Thank you for this information, however, as i am still some what new to php how would the code look if I wanted to use the switch structure?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the names of the required fields as a key, and an error message as a value. Then loop through this array. Use the keys in the `$_POST` superglobal to see if it's been set. If it's not set, throw the error message you defined as the value. Something along the lines of:

```
$required_parameters = array(
    "bottomair"  => "Maketable bottom air temp is required",
    "topair"     => "Maketable top air temp is required",
    // etc
);

$errorslist = array();

foreach($required_parameters as $key => $error)
{
    if(empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $errorslist[] = $error; // append to list
    }
    else
    {
        $test = test_input($_POST[$key]);
        if (!filter_var($test, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$coldmin, "max_range"=>$coldmax)))) 
        {
            $errorslist[] = $errormsg; // <-- I don't know where you define errormsg, though
        }
    }
}
```

You can then loop through the `$errorslist` array as well to display all errors in a list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. However, after testing this code within my page I discovered that it does not work the way the rest of the code works. I do not know if this is due to an incorrectly type error or if I did not fill in some of the possible missing code, but for what ever reason this code section did not work. I will keep trying though.